# Increment class property attribute in setter

Tags: python, properties

I understand the concept of getter/setter in python. The thing I am not able to understand is, I need to add new value to the variable itself and I am not sure how I can achieve this with @property decorator.

The old code instantiates some variables and self increment them. I am trying to refactor the code and move those variables to a class and add @property/setter so that I can access them as attributes.

Old Code:

```
class ExistingCode(object):
   a = 0
   b = 0
   c = 0
   d = 0

   bunch of other code..

   a += 12
   b += 12
   c += 12
   d += 12
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
class Variables(object):
   def __init__(self):
        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
        d = 0

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, x)
        a = x

    ......
```

I am getting "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded". Please help.

Comment: You need to give the actual attribute a name _different_ from that of the property (like the example shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) for the `x` attribute.

Comment: @martineau - you are right. I have added the correct way of using the property. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The main problem was that I was using the same name for the attribute and the property as mentioned by @martineau. Also, I missed self in many places. Below is the working example.

```
class Variables(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.__a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, x):
        self.__a = x
```